# Как прописать путь в php скрипте для ubuntu

Tags: php, linux

Есть скрипт php.
В нем есть переменная: `$root_dir = __DIR__;`
Если сделать вывод: `echo getcwd() . "\n";`
То выведется: /home/каталог1/каталог2/каталог3
Подскажите пожалуйста, как переменной $root_dir присовить каталог2?
Т.е. нужно чтобы значением $root_dir был именно каталог2
Спасибо.

Answer (score 2):

dirname() - Возвращает имя родительского каталога из указанного пути

```
$root_dir = dirname(__DIR__)
```

Answer (score 0):

Вы можете сделать `$path_array = explode(DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR, $path);` и получить массив из каталогов. Затем забрать нужный индекс `$path_array[$index]`, учитывая, какая последовательность для вас будет правильной (слева-направо — просто `$index = число;`, а справа-налево, что в вашем случае вероятнее, если вы используете `chdir('../')`, `$index = count($path_array) - число;`). Не забывайте, что путь, в unix системах начинается с `/` и первый (нулевой) элемент массива будет пустой строкой, когда в windows системе путь будет начинаться с диска. При этом учтите, что `getcwd` не всегда может возвращать путь, если права на чтение ограничены для linux-пользователя.

Из [документации](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.chdir.php):

> Замечание: Когда опция safe mode включена, PHP проверяет, имеет ли каталог, с которым вы собираетесь работать, такой же UID (владельца), как и выполняемый скрипт.

Из личных рассуждений: константа быстрее `chdir` и изменение текущей директории может вызвать в дальнейшем коде ошибки, которые будет непросто отловить, если не вернуть `chdir` в исходный каталог.

Answer (score -1):

Решил. Может кому и пригодится.
Это удаляем `$root_dir = __DIR__;` и пишем 
`$root_dir = getCwd();
chdir ("../");
$root_dir = getCwd();`
И проверяем текущий каталог выводом на экран `echo getcwd() . "\n";break;`